# Dimension of certain linear systems on a cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth degree $3$ hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$. Let $C$ be a smooth hyperplane section of $S$. Let $l$ be a line on $S$. It can be deduced that $h^0(\mathcal O_S(2C-2l)) \leq 4$. Can it happen that $h^0(\mathcal O_S(2C-2l)) = 4$?

In general, is there a recipe to compute $h^0(\mathcal O_S(nC-2l))$ for any positive integer $n \geq 2$ by interpreting $S$ as $\mathbb P^2$ blown up at $6$ points in general linear position and translating this cohomology computation to the cohomology computation of certain sheaves on $\mathbb P^2$ or otherwise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a contraction $\pi \colon S \to \mathbb{P}^2$ such that
$$
l \sim 2h - e_2 - e_3 - e_4 - e_5 - e_6,
$$
where $h$ is the pullback of a line under $\pi$ and $e_1,\dots,e_6$ are the exceptional divisors of $\pi$.
Then $C - l \sim h - e_1$ and $2C - 2l \sim 2(h - e_1)$. Now, the linear system $|h - e_1|$ gives a contraction $S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $\mathcal{O}_S(C - l)$ is the pullback of $\mathcal{O}(1)$, hence
$$
H^0(S, \mathcal{O}_S(2C - 2l)) \cong
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(2))
$$
is 3-dimensional.

Comment: Since $nC-2l \sim  2(h-e_1) +(n-2)C$. Can we say something about its $h^0$?

Comment: Sure, $h-e_1$ is nef, $C$ is ample, so if $n > 2$ then higher cohomology vanish and you can compute $h^0$ be Riemann-Roch.

Comment: I have one final doubt. For $h^1$ vanishing of $nC-2l$, are you using Kodaira vanishing on $nC-2l$ or are you using something else?

Comment: Yes, Kodaira vanishing.